# Cypher statement with distinct match conditions is returning the same result

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4j as a database to store voting information related to another database object.

I have a Vote object which has fields:

- `type:String` with values of `UP` or `DOWN`.
- `argId:String` which is a string ID value linking to a unique argument object

I am trying to query the number of votes assigned to a given argId using the following queries:

```
MATCH (v:Vote) WHERE v.argId = '214' AND v.type='DOWN'
RETURN {downvotes: COUNT(v)} AS votes
UNION
MATCH (v:Vote) WHERE v.argId = '214' AND v.type='UP'
RETURN {upvotes: COUNT(v)} AS votes
```

Note that this above cypher -- works and returns the expected result result like so:

```
[
 {
   "downvotes": 1
 },
 {
   "upvotes": 10
 }
]
```

But I feel like the query could be a bit neater and want to write something like this:

```
MATCH (v:Vote) WHERE v.argId = '214' AND v.type='UP'
MATCH (b:Vote) WHERE b.argId = '214' AND b.type='DOWN'
RETURN {upvotes: COUNT(v), downvotes: COUNT(b)}
```

Just reading it through, I think it makes sense, b and v are declared as separate variables, so all should be good (so I thought).

But running it given me this:

```
{
  "upvotes": 10,
  "downvotes": 10
}
```

But it should be what I have above.

Why is this?

I'm kinda new to neo4j and cypher so I've probably not understood how cypher works fully.

Can anyone shine any light?

Thank you!

p.s. I'm using Neo4j 3.5.6 and running the queries via the Desktop web browser app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you run this query you will get a clearer picture of what is happeneing. Your query produces a cartesian product of the upvotes(10) and the downvotes(1). The product is a result set of 10 rows. When they are subsequently counted, there are ten of each.

```
MATCH (v:Vote) WHERE v.argId = '214' AND v.type='UP'
MATCH (b:Vote) WHERE b.argId = '214' AND b.type='DOWN'
RETURN v.type, b.type
```

In order to get the result you want you need to filter the values and count them individually.

Rather than have two match statements, have a single match statement that retreives all of the values of interest and then use a conditional statement to filter them into upvotes and downbotes buckets.

Something like this may suit you.

```
MATCH (v:Vote {argId: '214'}) 
WHERE v.type IN ['UP', 'DOWN']
RETURN { 
          upvotes: count(CASE WHEN v.type = 'DOWN' THEN 1 END), 
          downvotes: count(CASE WHEN v.type = 'UP' THEN 1 END) 
       } AS vote_result
```

Using APOC you could do something like this whereby you use the type values themselves to aggregate the counts and then use APOC to convert it to a map with the types as the keys in the map.

```
MATCH (v:Vote {argId: '214'}) 
WHERE v.type IN ['UP', 'DOWN']
WITH [v.type, count(*)] AS vote_pair
RETURN apoc.map.fromPairs(collect(vote_pair)) AS votes
```